# How to set home page asynchronously in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous

I am trying to set the home page of the Flutter app asynchronously, but that is not working because the `build` method cannot have async properties.

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  // Widget homeWidget;
  // @override
  // void initState() async {
  //   super.initState();
  //   homeWidget = (await AuthUser.getCurrentUser() != null)
  //       ? NavBarPage()
  //       : OnBoardingWidget();
  // }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'WizTkt',
      theme: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
          appBarTheme: Theme.of(context)
              .appBarTheme
              .copyWith(brightness: Brightness.dark),
          primaryColor: Colors.blue),
      home: (await AuthUser.getCurrentUser() != null)
        ? NavBarPage()
        : OnBoardingWidget(),
    );
  }
}
```

As you can see in the code, I also tried to use `initState` to set the homepage widget but I cannot make initState an asynchronous function. I feel like there is a better way to choose your homepage in Flutter. What am I missing?

Do note that `AuthUser.getCurrentUser()` has to be an async function because I use the `SharedPreferences` library to obtain the login token stored in memory.

Comment: Hello, you can use FutureBuilder :) (https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use FutureBuilder which allows you to build an Widget in a future time.
Here an example:

```
class OnBoardingWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const OnBoardingWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<OnBoardingWidget> createState() => _OnBoardingWidgetState();
}


class _OnBoardingWidgetState extends State<OnBoardingWidget> {
  final Future<String> _waiter = Future<String>.delayed(
    const Duration(seconds: 2), () => 'Data Loaded',
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: FutureBuilder<String>(
        future: _waiter,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
          Widget wdgt;
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            wdgt = Text('Result: ${snapshot.data}');
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            wdgt = Text('Ops ops ops');
          } else {
            wdgt = Text('Not ready yet');
          }
          return Center(child: wdgt);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! The example was really helpful.